# How capybara matches elements

Tags: ruby, capybara

How does capybara access/finds/matches html elements? I come from a watir background so for me capybara is a bit high level and I can't quite really get the grasp of it even with the tutorials. let's say for example we have element

```
<input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Question" tabindex="120">
```

so how do I make capybara click that button? On watir-webdriver I could easily do a `browser.button(:id => "submit-button").click` what's the capybara equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click_button("Post Your Question") should work for you. Check out the [Capybara Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105).

EDIT: To expand on this when you want to click a button you will use the click_button method and pass the value as a parameter to this method.

Comment: Just confirming, so capybara matches the 'value' of the element?

Comment: Not only the value.. But the element can be found "by text, value or id" according to the Capybara documentation.

(http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method)

Comment: I guess capybara can handle the matching wothout us explicitly saying what we want to match since he will match them in id, name and value. Thanks.